# Heroku Cedar: How to scale WEB dynos based on time of day

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, automation

I want my Rails 3.1 app to scale up to 1 web dyno at 8am, then down to 0 web dynos at 5pm.

BUT, I do not want to sign up for a paid service, and I cannot count on my home computer being connected to the internet.

It seems like the Heroku Scheduler should make this trivial. Any quick solutions or links?

Comment: To clarify/simplify: from ruby, how do you add 1 new web dyno to your existing app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is 'yes' you can do this from scheduler and it's trivial once you know the answer:

1. Add a heroku config var with your app name: heroku config:add APP_NAME:blah
2. Add gem 'heroku' to your Gemfile
3. In order to verify, manually scale up/down your app: heroku ps:scale web=2
4. Add a rake task to lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:

   ```
   desc "Scale up dynos"
   task :spin_up => :environment do
     heroku = Heroku::Client.new('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
     heroku.ps_scale(ENV['APP_NAME'], :type=>'web', :qty=>2)
   end
   # Add a similar task to Spin down
   ```
5. Add the Scheduler addon: heroku addons:add scheduler:standard
6. Use the Scheduler web interface to add "rake spin_up" at whatever time you like
7. Add a rake spin_down task and schedule it for whenever.

**Notes:**
Step 1 is needed because I couldn't find any other way to be certain of the App name (and I use 'staging' and 'production' environments for my apps.

Step 3 is required because otherwise the ruby command errors out as it requires that you first agree (via Yes/No response) that you will be charged money as a result of this action.

In step 4, I couldn't find any docs about how to do this with an API key via the heroku gem, so it looks like user/pass is required.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: this returns error "RestClient::UnprocessableEntity: 422 Unprocessable Entity"

Comment: Did you skip step 3? Otherwise, I have no idea what would cause that (assuming the same stack and all). But you could try to rescue the error and see what it says.

Comment: If you are getting a 422 it means you haven't told heroku what your worker process is meant to do.  Have a look at the heroku documentation here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job It will tell you to create a Procfile that contains your worker definition.

Answer (score 11):

Just implemented this approach (good answer above @dnszero), thought I would update the answer with Heroku's new API.

Add your app name as a heroku config variable

```
 require 'heroku-api'
  desc "Scale UP dynos"
   task :spin_up => :environment do
     heroku = Heroku::API.new(:api_key => 'YOUR_ACCOUNT_API_KEY')
     heroku.post_ps_scale(ENV['APP_NAME'], 'web', 2)
   end
```

This is with  heroku (2.31.2), heroku-api (0.3.5)

Answer (score 3):

You can scale your web process to zero by

`heroku ps:scale web=0`

or back to 1 via

`heroku ps:scale web=1`

you'd then have to have a task set to run at 8 that scales it up and one that runs at 17 that scales it down. Heroku may require you to verify your account (ie enter credit card details) to use the Heroku Scheduler plus then you'd have to have the Heroku gem inside your app and your Heroku credentials too so it can turn your app on or off.

But like Neil says - you get 750hrs a month free which can't roll over into the next month so why not just leave it running all the time?

Comment: My bad, I meant to scale from 1 dyno to 2. My goal is to avoid the annoying 20 second spin up time during the workday (and to support Heroku by paying them for it, rather than hacking around with Pingdom, etc).

Answer (score 1):

See also this complete gist, which also deals with the right command to use from the Heroku scheduler: https://gist.github.com/maggix/8676595

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to implement this in 2017 and saw that the Heroku gem used by the accepted answer has been deprecated in favor of the 'platform-api' gem.  I just thought I'd post what worked for me, since i haven't seen any other posts with a more up-to-date answer.

Here is my rake file that scales my web dynos to a count of 2.  I used 'httparty' gem to make a PATCH request with appropriate headers to the Platform API, as per their [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation), in the "Formation" section.

```
require 'platform-api'
require 'httparty'

desc "Scale UP dynos"
task :scale_up => :environment do
  headers = {
    "Authorization" => "Bearer #{ENV['HEROKU_API_KEY']}",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "Accept" => "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
  }

  params = {
    :quantity => 2,
    :size => "standard-1X"
  }

  response = HTTParty.patch("https://api.heroku.com/apps/#{ENV['APP_NAME']}/formation/web", body: params.to_json, headers: headers)

  puts response
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As an update to @Ren's answer, Heroku's [Platform API gem](https://github.com/heroku/platform-api) makes this really easy.

```
heroku = PlatformAPI.connect_oauth(<HEROKU PLATFORM API KEY>)
heroku.formation.batch_update(<HEROKU APP NAME>, {"updates" => 
  [{"process" => <PROCESS NAME>, 
  "quantity" => <QUANTITY AS INTEGER>, 
  "size" => <DYNO SIZE>}]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on the cedar stack, you won't be able to scale to zero web dynos without changing the procfile and deploying.

Also, why bother if you get one free dyno a month (750 dyno hours, a little over a month in fact)?